# Apache Camel get empty response from jetty

Tags: apache, apache-camel

I face a complex case.
What I'm doing is as following steps:

1)  `<from uri="jetty:http://0.0.0.0:30100/jetty/test"/>`

2) `<to uri="hazelcast-client:master-test-series" />`

3)  `<to uri="bean:modelSeriesWrapperTest" />`

4)

> ```
> <split parallelProcessing="true" streaming="true">    
>     <simple>${body}</simple>    <to uri="direct:dw.model.test"/>   
>     </split>
> ```

5) From another route

> ```
> <from uri="direct:dw.model.test"/>
>    <aggregate strategyRef="myAggregatorStrategy"
>               completionTimeout="1000">
>               <correlationExpression>
>                   <constant>true</constant>
>               </correlationExpression>
>               <marshal ref="modelSeriesVariantColourGson" />
>               <camel:to uri="file:src/data/catask/output?fileName=output.xml"/>
>   </aggregate>
> ```

The problem is that the jetty response is empty. I use TCP trace to track the request and response, the Content-Length is 0. But the output.xml file has correct JSON format content.
Even I cross the `<camel:to uri="file:src/data/catask/output?fileName=output.xml"/>`. The jetty response is still empty.

I try the InOut pattern, it doesn't work as well. 
It seems jetty return directly, not waiting split done. I try to set In and Out body, it doesn't work either. I Google every case that I can image. There is no helpful case. 
Could you please help me? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

If you want the jetty response to include whatever information from your aggregator, then you must use the splitter only approach as documented at:

- http://camel.apache.org/composed-message-processor.html

The splitter has built-in aggregation, and that ensures when the splitter is done, it aggregates also, and then you can use that as the jetty response.

When you use `<aggregate>` then it becomes a separate exchange. To understand this more then read more about the aggregate eip, and other SO, and in various Camel books etc.